# Forge and Autodesk construction cloud

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-construction-cloud

How can I make a dashboard for autodesk construction cloud modules like (RFIs, assets, etc) in my Autodesk Forge app using Dot Net Core?

Answer (score 0):

Dashboard usually a client side thing, there are some popular JS libs which can help you to create fancy UI, what kind of Dashboard do you wan? This should not be related to Dot Net Core..